# Выпадающее меню при наведении на всю ширину экрана

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, вёрстка

https://codepen.io/Dasha_Novikova/pen/mdyOwXN

Добрый вечер. У меня есть выпадающее меню при hover. Как правильно сделать выпадающее меню на всю ширину?(как на фото). Если его делать, так как и предыдущие, то проблема в том что нужно будет ему задавать большую ширину, а оно на позиционировании и при адаптации будут большие проблемы (или нет?)).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я решила вынести его к обертке, чтобы не нужно было указывать ширину в пикселях, а указать в процентах и оно без проблем позиционировалось бы так как нужно.

Но теперь проблема, как сделать его активным при hover?

Нашла что-то на js, но оно меню отображает, но когда пытаюсь навести мышку на область меню, оно пропадает.

```
$('.class').hover(
    function(){
        $('.drop-down__mega-menu').css('display','block');
    }
);
```

Подскажите как правильно и лучше все это делают?

Answer (score 1):

Вы с выпадашкой потеряли связь, когда вывели её из родителя. Теперь лучше так (через opacity будет без скачков всяких):

```
<li class="drop__down-menu" id="page-link">
    <a class="drop__down-link" href="#">Pages</a>
</li>

.drop-down__mega-menu{
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none
}


$('#page-link').mouseover(function () {
  $('.drop-down__mega-menu').css({
    'opacity': 1,
    'pointer-events': 'auto'
  });
});

$('.drop-down__mega-menu').mouseleave(function () {
  $(this).css({
    'opacity': 0,
    'pointer-events': 'none'
  });
});

$('.menu__header-list li:not(#page-link)').mouseover(function () {
  $('.drop-down__mega-menu').css({
    'opacity': 0,
    'pointer-events': 'none'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Основная проблема в том что у вас селектор **.top-search-form input** из-за паддингов вылазит за пределы родительского контейнера ширина которого равна 1170px. Чтобы применить падинги для селектора **.top-search-form input** и избежать данной проблемы вам нужно использовать свойство box-sizing: border box (по умолчанию content-box).

**border box** - изменяет режим расчёта ширины элемента на описанный выше: теперь ширина элемента включает и рамку, и внутренние отступы и, собственно, ширину содержания самого элемента.

```
  .top-search-form input {box-sizing: border-box;}
```

Что касается ховера для выпадающего меню вы можете ставить задержку через css свойство transition.

```
  .drop__down-list:hover { transition-delay: 0s; }
  .drop__down-list { transition-delay: 0.3s; }
```