# Меню открывается и закрывается

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Пытаюсь сделать двохуровневое адаптивное меню. 
Вроде что-то получилось, но есть проблема, когда первый раз нажимать на пункт меню, то оно открывается и сразу закрывается, а потом работает нормально.

```
$('.menu__header-btn').on('click', function(){
  $('.menu__header-list').slideToggle();
});

$('.drop__down-menu').on('click', function(){
  $(this).children('.drop__down-list').slideToggle();
});
```

Вот код - https://codepen.io/Dasha_Novikov/pen/NWPpWaK

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1059541/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%8e-%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0  ?

Comment: @Kirill там уже все работает, но это меню адаптивное

Comment: у Вас же оно и по ховеру, и по клику открывается - может быть, в этом проблема?

Comment: @humster_spb ну смотрите, у мобильной версии нету же понятия hover, там есть только клик. И почему оно так работает только при 1 нажатии, а при всех последующий все работает нормально

Comment: в мобильной версии ховер срабатывает по клику. и клик срабатывает. получается дабл-клик. предлагаю для мобильной версии отменить открытие по ховеру (с помощью медиа-запросов), оставить только клик и посмотреть, что будет

Comment: @humster_spb спасибо вроде помогло) Я думала, что там не может работать ховер( а он и в правду работает. Можете написать в ответ, чтобы я закрыла вопрос)

Comment: Даша, написал )

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102376/discussion-between---and-humster-spb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В мобильной версии ховер срабатывает по клику. И клик срабатывает тоже. Получается дабл-клик. В этом корень проблемы.

Предлагаю для мобильной версии отменить открытие по ховеру (с помощью медиа-запросов) и оставить только клик.